# django.contrib.auth.views.login does nothing, why?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

When I try to go to URL of view with `@login_required`, it redirects me to login form. But the rendered form has no `action=`attribute and when I click submit button nothing happens.  But when I go to `/admin/` I got the working login form. After I log in that way all views are working. I'm using `admin_bootstrap` so it's different login form. But why the default one is acting that way?

Relevant code:

**mySubApp/views.py**:

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at index.")
```

**mainApp/urls.py**:

```
#login
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='LogMeIn'),

#mySubApp
url(r'^subapp/', include('mySubApp.urls')),
```

**mySubApp/urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

**settings.py**:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'LogMeIn'
```

Do I need to create a custom login form to make it work or what?

Comment: Why don't you have an action attribute in your login form?

Comment: That's the root of my question : I did't write ANY login form I was counting that when I use `django.contrib.auth.views.login` it's all it will use some pre written login form(it's got the form without action from somewhere) am I'm wrong and should just do everything mentioned in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in; or I just need to write login template? I just assumed that "Do not repeat yourself" philosophy means it should work "out of the box"

Comment: What does the template look like? There is an example template in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login. Maybe there is a faulty template from some plugin that's bothering you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [define your own templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) when using the authentication views (they aren't provided by defualt):

> Django provides several views that you can use for handling login, logout, and password management. These make use of the stock auth forms but you can pass in your own forms as well.
>
> Django provides no default template for the authentication views - however the template context is documented for each view below.

So create a `registration/login.html`:

```
<form action="{% url auth:login %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: How do you know that I need to name folder 'registration'. Where can I check this schema??

Comment: I did exactly what you said  but with no effect, I can put anything in `templates/registration/login.html` like `<h3> Wrong</h3>` but it still renders same form as before

Comment: You are using the [`django.contrib.auth` views to login](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py) , those are the template it uses. There are plenty of reasons this would not be working. Did you set `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your settings? Are other template working?

Comment: `Django provides no default template for the authentication views - `  Does anyone know WHY Django has chosen to not provide default templates?  I, too was a bit surprised as I had thought it would work like the Admin and simply provide a drop-in login tool to start boilerplating a site quickly.